# Where is here possible atomic update violation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I am facing an unexpected warning and want to check is it a bug or not

the warning is

> ESLint:
> Possible race condition: `gridItem.card` might be
> reassigned based on an outdated value of
> `gridItem.card`.(require-atomic-updates)

I have checked this page https://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-atomic-updates , and seems that for my code everything should be ok, because the property assignment is independent from it's old value.
[image]

```
function ChangeCardDialog({ gridItem }:{ gridItem: GridItem }) {
    const updateCard = useCallback(async () => {
        const card = await fetchCard(gridItem.userId);
        gridItem.card = card; // here the warning
    }, [gridItem.card, gridItem.userId]);
    
    ...
}
```

this the screen from IDE
[image]

Comment: Without knowing what `gridItem` is nor what `fetchCard` does, we cannot tell whether it's a bug or not.